# I want to deploy my full stack application with AWS amplify but doesn't work

Tags: deployment, mysql-workbench, aws-amplify, react-fullstack

I'm new and learnig React and mySQL. I've just finished my app with React and mySQL(WorkBench) and I'd like to deploy my app with Amplify. I tried to deploy it through my github repo but URL created for app shows 'Page not found'.

(I'm asked to deploy AWS Amplify from company.)

To be honest, I don't know whether my folder composition is correct to deploy and how to deploy full stack app with amplify.(I could deploy SPA app...)

Below link is my app folder structure.

[image: 1]

Below is my app.js code(lambda function with Express)

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless- 
express/middleware')
const mysql = require('mysql2')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: 'database-1.clw5xqnhqbio.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
 user: 'root',
 password: 'Ryotakagi',
 database: 'awstaskmanager'
})

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
 next()
});

app.get('/tasks', (req, res) => {
 const TASK_QUERY = "select * from awstaskmanager.tasks"
 connection.query(TASK_QUERY, (err, response) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else res.send(response)
  })
})

app.post('/addTask', (req, res) => {
 const ADD_QUERY = `insert into awstaskmanager.tasks (task) 
 values ('${req.body.task}')`
 connection.query(ADD_QUERY, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else res.send('add task')
 })
})

app.delete('/deleteTask/:taskid', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.params.taskid);
 const DELETE_QUERY = `DELETE FROM awstaskmanager.tasks where 
  (taskid=${req.params.taskid})`
 connection.query(DELETE_QUERY, (err, res) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
 })
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
 console.log("App started")
});


module.exports = app
```

Of course, my local environment is correctly working.

**I need to submit this app to my company I want to join, so I REALLY want to complete this app...**

So, could you tell me the folder structure is right and how to deploy full stack app which is already finished?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `node/express` server into `Lambda` function.

Specific `server` directory is not necessary, since `Amplify` won't run this server. So you need to move your `node/express` code into Lambda function you've created.

If you're using MySQL, you can use `AWS RDS` using [`AWS SDK`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html)

---

When using `Amplify`(serverless stack), all your backend should be separated from the project. [`Amplify Hosting`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting) can't run `NodeJS` server like for example using [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

---

so since you've created an Amplify project, you can add Lambda function using `amplify add function` command and choose Express server.

and copy your `node/express` code into that and run `amplify push`

for your frontend, you can access the `node/express` server using the name you provided when creating a Lambda function. Basically when Lambda function created and deployed (using `amplify push` command), [`Amplify CLI`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/) stores the API Gateway URL in your project, in `aws-exports.js`.

*EDIT*

If you want to have your React app inside `client` folder, you need to edit [build settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html), since you need to `cd` into `client` and run `npm run build`

But if your structure would be like this, you don't need to configure.

```
> amplify
> node_modules
> public
> src
> package.json
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering specifically so much!!!!!!   So, my directly structure should be just the client directly and amplify directly, right?

Comment: yes, I've updated my answer regarding the frontend build

Comment: Thanks for answering twice!!!! I'm gonna try as you told me!!!

Comment: I want to ask you again sorry.  If I want to connect to server side(Lambda function created as Express server) from my frontend,  the path to connect server side should be like
 'my rds endpoint/name created for Lambda finc/addTask' ?

Just in case, I added pic of lambda function file code.
I really appreciate your grateful kindness. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can install `aws-amplify` npm package on frontend. And access the API like this `import { API } from 'aws-amplify'; await API.get('apiName', '/tasks')`. I forgot to tell you, you can create API endpoint using `amplify add api` command, and choose your created Lambda function when asked to use existing Lambda function or create new one.